# HashMap (Open Addressing) Implementation VERY slow

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

For some reason my HashMap implementation using open addressing is running very slowly with large data sets but I cannot figure out exactly why. Can anyone provide some insight? Im just a data structures student trying to figure out why my data structure is so inefficient.

I run it on smaller data sets and it works in the time i expect it to, but as soon as I ramp it up it fails on me.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
/**
 * @author Cameron Berger
 * HASHMap if a data structure which is suppose to be faster than an AVL tree
 * for set() and get(), however, I was unsucessful in this. But it works!
 */
public class HASHMap<K extends Comparable<K>,V> implements Map<K,V>{
  private class Node{
    public K k;
    public V val;

    public Node(K key, V value) {
      k      = key;
      val    = value;
    }
  }

  //time to implement
  private List<Node> arr;
  private int numKeys;
  private int size;
  private double loadFactor = 0.5;
  /**
   * Constructor for HASHMap
   **/
  public HASHMap(){
    size = 16;
    arr = new ArrayList<Node>(Collections.nCopies(size, null));
    numKeys = 0;
  }

  public V get(K key){
    int index = Math.abs(key.hashCode())%size;
    Node n;
    for(int i=index; ; i=(i+1)%size){
      n = arr.get(i);
      if (n == null)
        return null;
      else if(key.compareTo(n.k)==0)
        return n.val;
    }
  }

  public void set(K key, V value){
    int index = Math.abs(key.hashCode())%size;
    Node n;
    for(int i=index; ; i=(i+1)%size){
      n = arr.get(i);
      if (n == null){
        Node temp = new Node(key, value);
        arr.set(i, temp);
        numKeys++;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(Double.compare((numKeys/size),loadFactor)>0){
      this.reinitialize();
    }
  }
  /**
   * reinitialize reinitializes the HashMap if the loadFactor condition is met
   * or there is too much spill over
   **/
  private void reinitialize(){
    int nsize = size*2;
    List<Node> nArr = new ArrayList<Node>(Collections.nCopies(nsize, null));
    Node temp;

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
      temp = arr.get(i);
      if(temp!=null){
        K key = temp.k;
        int index = Math.abs(key.hashCode())%nsize;
        for(int j=index; ; j=(j+1)%nsize){
          Node n = nArr.get(j);
          if(n==null){
            nArr.set(j, temp);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    this.size = nsize;
    this.arr = nArr;
  }

  public int size(){ return numKeys; }

  public List<K> keys(){
    List<K> keylist = new ArrayList<K>();
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
      Node n = arr.get(i);
      if(n!=null)
        keylist.add(n.k);
    }
    return keylist;
  }

  public List<V> values(){
    List<V> valuelist = new ArrayList<V>();
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
      Node n = arr.get(i);
      if(n!=null)
        valuelist.add(n.val);
    }
    return valuelist;
  }
}
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not certain how you tested this since you are missing many methods and some of the ones you have don't match the signatures in the `Map` interface.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is a problem in this part:

```java
    if(Double.compare((numKeys/size),loadFactor)>0){
      this.reinitialize();
    }
```

Since `numKeys` and `size` are both ints, this is integer division - i.e. it rounds down. So the result of the division will only be greater than `loadFactor` when `numKeys` and `size` are equal, which effectively means your class behaves like a hashtable with a load factor of 1, instead 0.5. That causes your open-addressing scheme to deteriorate to O(n) complexity instead of O(1).

The solution is to change this condition so that it does the comparison correctly. First, be careful when you divide ints but you want the answer to be a double; you need to cast to double before dividing. Second, don't use `Double.compare` when you could use `<` or `>` instead. A fixed version looks like this:

```java
    if((double) numKeys / size > loadFactor) {
        this.reinitialize();
    }
```

Or, to avoid division completely, you could equivalently test if `numKeys > loadFactor * size`.